# How to set the name of a new SPListItem programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, splistitem, splist

I have a custom list which can contain a CustomContentType. This is how i create a new item:

```
//Create root folder
SPListItem rootItem = navigation.Items.Add();
SPContentType folderType = navigation.ContentTypes["ListLevel"];
rootItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "root";
rootItem["ContentTypeId"] = folderType.Id;
rootItem.Update();
```

The problem is, when I'm looking at my list after this I see that:

[image]

When I go to the list via a webbrowser and create the content type manually, everthing is fine. (Which means that the Title is "root" and not the ID).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you both for you answers!

The solution was a mixture of both answers. Additionally you have to reload the list:

```
            //Create root folder
            SPListItem rootItem = navigation.Items.Add();
            SPContentType contentType = navigation.ContentTypes["ListLevel"];

            rootItem["ContentTypeId"] = contentType.Id;
            rootItem["Title"] = "root";
            rootItem.Update();
            navigation.Update();

            rootItem = navigation.GetItemById(rootItem.ID);
            rootItem["Name"] = "root";
            rootItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

The "name" field corresponds to the filename. Despite what you see in the column heading, the 1125_.000 is the filename of the list item, which is automatically generated if you don't supply one:

```
rootItem["Name"] = "myname";
```

"Name" is a built-in field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content type ID first then do a rootItem.update(). 
Set your field content after that.

```
//Create root folder 
SPListItem rootItem = navigation.Items.Add(); 
SPContentType folderType = navigation.ContentTypes["ListLevel"]; 
rootItem["ContentTypeId"] = folderType.Id; 
rootItem.Update(); 
rootItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "root"; 
rootItem.Update();
```